# nodejs - Removing user completely on disconnect (socketio)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My socketio collecting users script;

```
var users = [];

io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {    
socket.on('new user', function(data) {    
socket.nickname = data.nick;    
users[socket.nickname] = socket;    
});

});
```

I want to remove the disconnected user. Done this;

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
delete users[socket.nickname];
});
```

After that, there is no errors. But when I do

```
console.log(typeof users[socket.nickname]);
```

it gives me output of `object`

Also there are still some garbage data left about the user. (socket events listeners, namespace). What is the proper way to remove user completely without leaving any data ?

Answer (score 2):

```
socket.on('disconnect', function() {
socket.get('nickname', function(err, user) {
  delete users[user];
  io.sockets.emit('update', users);
});
});
```